# Java split strings at specific points

Tags: java, string, split

I am trying to take user inputted text and split it into an array of strings. The user is supposed to enter the line break in the form of "%n". How do I get it to split the string at that point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
String[] lines = yourString.split("%n");
```

Answer (score 1):

Please, take a look at [documentation on `String.split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) first. It can be used the following way:

```
public class Main {
  public static void main(String... args) {
    for (String line : "aaa%nbbb%nccc".split("%n")) {
      System.out.println(line);
    }
  }
}
```

Will give you:

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure, that the line break will be "\n", there should be nothing special with it. Have you tried the `String.split(...)` method?

By the way, there were a lot of discussions on this topic.

Answer (score 1):

Using String's split method like this.

```
String input = "abcd%nefgh%nijkl";
String[] inputSplitted = input.split("%n");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(inputSplitted));
```

Output: `[abcd, efgh, ijkl]`

Answer (score 1):

```
str.substring(startIndex,endIndex);
```

Or

```
String lines[]=input.split("\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public String[] split(String regex, int limit)
```

or

```
public String[] split(String regex)
```